# Process scheduler

Tags: c, process, operating-system, scheduler

So I have to implement a discrete event cpu scheduler for my OS class, but I don't quite understand what how it works. Every explanation/textbook I've read always put things in terms a little too abstract for me to be able to figure out how it actually works, nor does it put things in terms of cpu bursts and io bursts (some did but still not helpful enough).

I'm not posting any of the code I have (I wrote a lot actually but I think I'm going to rewrite it after I figure out (in the words of Trump) what is actually going on). Instead I just want help to figure out a sort of pseudocode I can then implement.
We are given multiple processes with an Arrival Time (AT), Total Cpu (TC), Cpu burst (CB), and Io burst (IO).

Suppose that I was given: p1 (AT=1, TC=200, CB=10, IO=20) and p2 (AT=1000, TC=200, CB=20, IO=10). And suppose I am implementing a First Come First Serve scheduler.

I also put question marks (?) where I'm not sure.

```
Put all processes into eventQ
initialize all processes.state = CREATED
While(eventQueue not empty) process = eventQueue.getFront()

 if process.state==CREATED state, it can transition to ready
   clock= process.AT 
   process.state = READY
   then I add it back to the end (?) of the eventQueue.

 if process.state==READY, it can transition to run 
   clock= process.AT + process.CPU_time_had + process.IO_time_had (?)  
   CPU_Burst = process.CB * Rand(b/w 0 and process.CB)
   if (CB >= process.TC - process.CPU_time_had) 
       then it's done I don't add it back
       process.finish_time = clock + CB
       continue
   else 
       process.CPU_time_had += CB
       (?) Not sure if I put the process into BLOCK or READY here
       Add it to the back of eventQueue (?)

 if process.state==BLOCK
    No idea what happens (?) 
    Or do things never get Blocked in FCFS (which would make sense)
    Also how do IO bursts enter into this picture???
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Look at arrival time of each thread, you can sort the queue such that arrival times occurring first appear before threads with later arrival times. Run the front of the queue's thread (this is a thread scheduler). Run the thread a burst at a time, when the burst's cpu time is up, enter a new event at the back of the queue with an arrival time of the current time plus the burst's io time (sort the queue again on arrival times). This way other threads can execute while a thread is performing io.

(My answer is assuming you are in the same class as me. [CIS*3110])

Comment: I'm glad someone understands it:)  I have no idea what a thread 'arrival time' might be, or what an 'IO burst' is:(

Comment: How does the IO burst enter into this picture? And so what you're saying is if p1's arrival time + cpu_burst < p2's arrival time (that didn't have any cpu burst) I pop p2 instead of p1? Even in FCFS scheduling scheme?

Comment: They aren't IO bursts. It's a CPU burst. Each CPU burst ends, whether by going out for IO, or by the thread terminating. In the input file, there are arrival times, these are when each thread arrives. So the first CPU burst arrives at the thread's arrival time. Each subsequent burst's arrival time is the time that the previous burst for this thread ended, plus the IO time of the previous burst. The idea is that the thread performs some stuff in the CPU, leaves for IO, then returns once it's done getting IO. So, schedule the threads, and shuffle the queue around whenever a thread is interrupted